# Maximum error of $\int_{1}^{2 m} \frac{1}{y} d y$ using the Trapezoid Rule

Tags: numerical-methods

Consider $\int_{1}^{2m} \frac{1}{y} d y$. Show that the integral can be calculated using Trapezoid Rule with maximum error
$$\frac{\left(2^{m}-1\right) h^{2}}{12}$$
for a given step length $h$.

---

**Answer** The error is given by $E = -f^{\prime \prime}(\xi) \frac{h^{3}}{6},\xi\in(1,2^m)$.

It must be the case that $\xi = 1$, but this is problematic because $\xi\in(1,2^m)$ and not $\xi\in[1,2^m)$.  This means that the maximum error is actually not $\frac{\left(2^{m}-1\right) h^{2}}{12}$, *but* the maximum error is less than  $\frac{\left(2^{m}-1\right) h^{2}}{12}$!

Also, I'm not sure what *"for a given step length $h$"* means?

Comment: By "maximum error", they mean "error bound". The error is *at most* as large as the given expression.

Comment: Oh, okay! Thanks. Now I get it. They mean $|E| \leq ..$, right? @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the boundaries are, I suppose you mean to integrate from $1$ to $2^m$ and not $1$ to $2m$? I also suppose you use $f(y)=\frac{1}{y}$.

In that case, the error is given by: $$-\frac{(2^m-1)h^2}{12}f''(\xi)$$
for suitable $\xi\in(1,2^m)$.

Now since $f''(\xi) = \frac{2}{\xi^3}$, this would lead to an error of
$$E=-\frac{2\cdot(2^m-1)h^2}{12\xi^3}$$

Now we can choose $\xi$ such that $\frac{2}{\xi^3}=1$ so that $\xi=2^{\frac{1}{3}}$ which is about $1.26<2^m$ assuming $m>0$ (else the integral would be simply $0$ as you would integrate from $1$ to $1$).

So for this $\xi$ we have that the absolute error is bounded above
$$|E|\leq\frac{(2^m-1)h^2}{12}$$

Answer (score 0):

If we apply the trapezoidal rule to the integral $\int_1^{2^m}\frac 1y dy$ (you must have a typo, the upper limit should be $2^m$), the error is given by
$$
-\frac{(2^m -1) h^2}{12} f''(\xi), \quad \xi \in (1, 2^m)
$$

where $h$ stands for the distance between consecutive integration nodes (this is the composite rule).

Now, since $|f''(\xi)| = \frac{2}{\xi^3} \leq 2$, you have that the absolute error is bounded by
$$
\frac{(2^m-1) h^2}{6}.
$$